# WKWebView load local page

Tags: swift, wkwebview

How to load a local HTML page into WKWebview ?

I set allowingReadAccessTo to the directory containing all files. But still get an error.

```
   if let testTempUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "index", withExtension: "html", subdirectory:"sub") {
                if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: testTempUrl.path) {

                    webViewWK.loadFileURL(testTempUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: testTempUrl.deletingLastPathComponent())


                } else {
                    askSiriWhy()
                }
            }
```

The HTML page loads without problem if I use UIWebView instead of WKWebView.

Comment: You'll get a lot of down votes (not from me, though) until you show us what you've tried. It's the only way we can help you without doing it for you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're using "allowingReadAccessTo" - Where is your file located?

```
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: testTempUrl.path) {

                    webViewWK.loadFileURL(testTempUrl, allowingReadAccessTo: testTempUrl.deletingLastPathComponent())

 }
```

why not just:

```
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: testTempUrl.path) {
    webViewWK.loadFileURL(testTempUrl)
}
```